# Extjs two different handlers for single component

Tags: extjs, event-handling, extjs4, dom-events

I have a window, and have two child items panel1, panel2. I have apply buttons in docked items. button is part of window...panel1, and panel2 does not have button.

I have to do different operations for Panel1, Panel2. If Panel1 is activated, and when use click on apply, it would call some handler, but when panel2 is activated, it calls handler of panel1. So, what should I do?

Here is my reference for calling handler:

```
'myxtype button[action=apply]':{
 click: someFunction
}
```

Is there any way to do operations for panel1, and panel2 with Same apply button? or anything else?

Comment: what do you mean by panel is active? the focus is on this panel? do you have a card layout and want to different actions based on which panel is in the foreground?

Comment: @JanS I have taken tabPanel in window. and In tabPanel has 2 items..panel1, and panel2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to do a switch in your eventhandler:

```
'myxtype button[action=apply]': {
    click: this.someFunction
},

someFunction: function (button) {
    var tab = button.up('tabpanel').getActiveTab();
    if (tab.title === 'tabtitle1') { // insert title of tab1 here
        handlerForPanel1(); // insert function for tab1 here
    } else {
        handlerForPanel2(); // insert function for tab2 here
    }
}
```

in extjs a component can only have one listener function for each event type
you can't assign different handlers based on the circumstances around this component
so the only solution is to dispatch the event in the event handler and delegate it to 2 different functions

Comment: button is child of tabPanel.
button is child of window.
window has 2 items. both are custom components, and button in bottom toolbar apply.

Comment: I know, whats the problem?

Comment: I want to call 2 different handler on single button. so, when panel1 is activated and when i click on apply button, it should execute someFunction, but, when panel2 is activated and when i click on apply button, it should execute other function..is it possible ?

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional information

Comment: If this answer was helpful please mark it as accepted so other users know that this solved the problem

Comment: I have used your approach. but, I want to ask that is there any way to registered multiple evetns on single button/component after rending button ? and those 2 handlers do different operation.

Comment: but my answer does exactly this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53903/discussion-between-rishabh-shah-and-jan-s)